# EntityFrameworkCore not adding entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am putting together a new web application template for myself using .AspNetCore 2.0 and EFCore 2.0.

In my test project I am doing some testing with both creating the context and adding to DbSets.

Here is the context creation method.

```
public static ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var basepath = GetBasePath("Application.UI");
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(basepath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
        //Set up configuration sources.

        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new ApplicationDbContext(builder.Options);
    }
```

Here is the test method where the error message is.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void AddContact_WithDates_ShouldGetAdded()
    {
        //Arrange
        var ct = new ContactUs
        {
            ContactWho = ContactWho.Support,
            Message = "Please call me about website problems",
            Email = "joe@joe.com",
            MessageSentTimestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
            FirstName = "Jim",
            LastName = "Simons",
            ReportingError = false,
            MobilePhone = "5555556666"
        };
        var appArgs = new[] {"TestApp"};
        var context = ApplicationDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(appArgs);
        //Act
        context.ContactUss.Add(ct);
        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(context);  
    }
```

The context is created correctly. ContactUs (ContactUss is the DbSet of ContactUs) is just a standard domain class.

[image: Context from immediate window]

But VS2017 is giving me a red squiggly under ct in the Add(ct) call with the error message

> Argument type ContactUs is not assignable to parameter of type TEntity

This has always been how I've worked with EF. Is there something new in Core that I'm missing?

Comment: there is nothing worng with that way, i'm using it too in my project and it works fine, I guess there is a problem somewhere else

Comment: First, this is an integration test, not a unit test. Second, *DON'T TEST THE FRAMEWORK*. You can safely assume that `Add` will in fact add the entity because EF Core is very well tested. It already has tests to ensure that functionality works correctly; creating your own is useless.

Comment: @Chris Pratt...The test was simply to verify that I could actually create the context and interact with it since I just started to use EF Core. I wasn't testing to see if the ADD method worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Visual Studio nor Resharper were alerting me to the solution for this error. But the error trace in the unit test UI showed System.Data.SqlClient file not found.

I added the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer package and this solved the issue.